# docker-compose rabbitmq service ports overwrite my node express ports

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file like:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:latest"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
  hellosign-callback-listener:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}blah/hellosign-callback-listener:${DOCKER_IMAGE_LABEL:-latest}
    init: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./debugging/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

And my ./debugging/Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV NODE_ENV=debugging \
    PORT=8080

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --uid 999 hellosign

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -qq install \
  curl \
  git \
  gnupg2 \
  netcat

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash
RUN apt-get -qq install nodejs
RUN npm install npm@latest -g

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g \
  Eficode/wait-for

EXPOSE 8080

COPY src/ .

USER hellosign

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

However, when I run my node application via *docker-compose up hellosign-callback-listener*, I find that the port it is trying to use is **5672** rather than **8080**.  I don't understand why **5672** seems to be overwriting the process.env.PORT and how to stop it so that'll it'll use the 8080 that I want the node express server to run on.

**EDIT**

This is the output from *docker-compose ps*

```
WARNING: The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
                          Name                                         Command               State           Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hellosign-callback-listener_hellosign-callback-listener_1   /bin/sh -c /usr/lib/node_m ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

This is the output from *docker-compose logs hellosign-callback-listener*

```
WARNING: The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Attaching to hellosign-callback-listener_hellosign-callback-listener_1
hellosign-callback-listener_1  | { AMQP_SEND_PASSWORD: 'guest',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   HOSTNAME: '2433ad7e8f4f',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   AMQP_SEND_HOST: 'rabbitmq',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   PORT: '5672',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   HOME: '/home/hellosign',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   AMQP_SEND_PORT: '5672',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   AMQP_SEND_LOGGING_TOPIC: 'topic',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   PATH:
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |    '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   AMQP_SEND_USERNAME: 'guest',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   AMQP_SEND_LOGGING_EXCHANGE: 'firehose',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   APPLICATION_ID: '55122888670320',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   ORGANISATION_ID: '8632477670016',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   PWD: '/usr/src/app',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   NODE_ENV: 'debugging',
hellosign-callback-listener_1  |   WAIT_FOR: 'rabbitmq:5672' }
```

which is essentially me doing a `console.log(process.env)` within my node application.

Comment: Mmmh, so it's the reverse what you said in title: node takes rabbit port? How do you verify node listen on 5672? That's seems non-sense, did you log the express code or your lsof command was confusing?

Comment: Have you tried setting env `PORT=8080 ` in docker-compose.yaml ?

Comment: can you run `docker-compose ps` and also `docker-compose log hellosign-callback-listener` and post the results?

Comment: @Mihai I've added the requested output. does that help?

Comment: @Slim lsof command?  But yes, i'm outputting the `process.env` structure in node, and also outputting `const listener = app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(listener.address())});`

Comment: @Jarede Yes it does, thanks. Do you have a .env file as well that you use for your project? My only explanation is that you have a .env and in there you define PORT=5672. If that is not so then this is really confusing...

Comment: @Mihai I do have an `.env` file but **PORT** isn't defined in it anywhere.

Comment: that's weird... In any case, can you add in your docker-compose file for the second service: "environment: - PORT=8080" and re-run your container?

Comment: @Mihai no luck, still saying it's listening on 5672

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193825/discussion-between-mihai-and-jarede).

Comment: mmm.... If you leave it to only "environment: -PORT" and run `docker-compose config` do you see the value populated with something?

Comment: @Mihai I think i replied to you in the chat, but when doing that, PORT is output as null

Comment: At this point I have no other suggestion than to write a script where you set the port and start your server (PORT=8080 node server.js) and use that as entrypoint. If this also fails then it means that you set that port somehow in your application... In the end I still think that you have some .env file "hidden" somewhere with this PORT variable declared. Otherwise it really doesn't make any sense :)